# Help finding small graphical file manager

Tags: debian, software-rec, file-manager, lightweight

I have a console only `debian` install. I installed `X`, and then `slim`, and now I would like to add a minimal file manager, one step up from the terminal/console... I installed `xfe`, but noticed that uses dozens of dependencies, is there anything more lightweight but yet graphical?

Comment: Try `midnight commander` shoter just `mc`. But as I know the `xfce` have own small and quick `pcmanfm`

Comment: `mc` or, even more minimalistic, `ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something lighter graphically you can use yes, but it is important to understand that a file manager is different from a *window manager*: a *file manager* as the name suggests will be responsible for assisting in controlling and managing files, folders, etc ... so there are other items that are installed with it the **XFE** is a good example of a lightweight file manager as well, but if you want you can try to use a combination of manager windows "*BlackBox*" which is very light and simple, and use the **MC** - "*Midnight Commander*" to assist you in managing files and folders, "*copy, delete, move, etc* ..." as I even got to use, is something very light and simple, but woe is doque question exactly you demand and how and where you want to use this setting, ok!

Comment: +1 For `mc`.  In addition to being light and fast, it is IMO one of the best pieces of [software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers) ever.  It's the always first thing I install and one of the things I use the most.

Comment: wow mc, graphical yet so console...

Answer (score 0):

The most light weight file managers I'm aware of are [emelFM2](http://emelfm2.net/) which I used in DSL a while back and XFM.  I've got a coworker that uses Arch and recommends nero(personally I haven't used it yet), unfortunately I'm not able to find a link or list of dependencies for nero right off.

Answer (score 0):

I find PCManFM and Thunar to be light enough.